# Constraining F# function parameter to multiple instantiations of a generic interface fails with FS0193

Tags: generics, interface, f#

I'm trying to constrain an F# function parameter to conform to multiple interfaces, which are in turn derived from the same generic interface declaration:

```ml
module GenericInterfaceTest =

  (* declare an interface using generic type *)
  type IReader<'a> =
    abstract member readValue : 'a

  (* constraining only int works *)
  let useReaderInt<'r when 'r :> IReader<int>> (reader : 'r) =
    (reader :> IReader<int>).readValue

  (* constraining only float works *)
  let useReaderFloat<'r when 'r :> IReader<float>> (reader : 'r) =
    (reader :> IReader<float>).readValue

  (* [FS0193] Type constraint mismatch.
     The type ''r' is not compatible with type 'IReader<float>' *)
  let useReaders<'r when 'r :> IReader<int> and 'r :> IReader<float>> (reader : 'r) =
    (reader :> IReader<int>).readValue, (reader :> IReader<float>).readValue

  (* [FS0193] Type constraint mismatch.
     The type ''r' is not compatible with type 'IReader<int>' *)
  let useReaders<'r when 'r :> IReader<float> and 'r :> IReader<int>> (reader : 'r) =
    (reader :> IReader<int>).readValue, (reader :> IReader<float>).readValue


  (* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Not using generic type works
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *)
  type IIntReader =
    abstract member readValue : int

  type IFloatReader =
    abstract member readValue : float

  (* works *)
  let useReaders<'r when 'r :> IIntReader and 'r :> IFloatReader> (reader : 'r) =
    (reader :> IIntReader).readValue, (reader :> IFloatReader).readValue


  (* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Using different generic declarations works
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *)
  type IReader2<'a> =
    abstract member readValue : 'a

  (* works *)
  let useReaders<'r when 'r :> IReader<int> and 'r :> IReader2<float>> (reader : 'r) =
    (reader :> IReader<int>).readValue, (reader :> IReader2<float>).readValue


  (* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Using type aliases does not work
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *)
  type IReaderInt = IReader<int>
  type IReaderFloat = IReader<float>

  (* [FS0193] Type constraint mismatch.
     The type ''r' is not compatible with type 'IReaderInt' *)
  let useReaders<'r when 'r :> IReaderFloat and 'r :> IReaderInt> (reader : 'r) =
    (reader :> IReader<int>).readValue, (reader :> IReader2<float>).readValue
```

Is this a compiler bug or limitation, or am I doing something wrong?

Is there another way of achieving this without having to write the code multiple times using concrete types?

Edit: I have found the issue on [fslang-suggestions](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1036): https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1036

It is a limitation involving type inference.

One of the comments mentions working around this by having intermediate non-generic interfaces inheriting generic specialisations. I would be very grateful if someone could help me with an example of how to do this - my best guess below does not work:

```ml
module GenericInterfaceTest2 =
  (* declare an interface using generic type *)
  type IReader<'a> =
    abstract member readValue : 'a

  type IReaderInt = inherit IReader<int>

  type IReaderFloat = inherit IReader<float>

  (* works *)
  let useReaders<'r when 'r :> IReaderInt> (reader : 'r) =
    (reader :> IReader<int>).readValue

  (* [FS0193] Type constraint mismatch.
     The type ''r' is not compatible with type 'IReaderFloat' *)
  let useReaders<'r when 'r :> IReaderInt and 'r :> IReaderFloat> (reader : 'r) =
    (reader :> IReaderInt).readValue, (reader :> IReaderFloat).readValue
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty, but it compiles:

```ml
type IReaderIntFloat =
    inherit IReader<int>
    inherit IReader<float>

let useReaders (reader : IReaderIntFloat) =
    (reader :> IReader<int>).readValue, (reader :> IReader<float>).readValue
```

Comment: Thank you Brian. 

While this compiles, it does not really solve my problem, since I would have to declare and implement an interface for every combination of readers that functions in my system depend upon (to adhere to interface segregation). 

My current best solution is to have the useReaders functions accept a parameter which is a tuple of the different interfaces required.

Comment: You’re right, but you’d have to declare the same interfaces as type parameter constraints in your preferred solution, so it seems quite similar to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-generic wrapper types and flexible types:

```ml
// Input type
type IReader<'a> =
    abstract member readValue : 'a

// Wrapper types
type IReaderInt =
    abstract readInt : int

type IReaderFloat =
    abstract readFloat : float

// Implementation
type NumberReader(intReader: IReader<int>, floatReader: IReader<float>) =
    interface IReaderInt with
        member _.readInt = intReader.readValue

    interface IReaderFloat with
        member _.readFloat = floatReader.readValue

// Helpers
let readInt (reader: #IReaderInt) =
    reader.readInt

let readFloat (reader: #IReaderFloat) =
    reader.readFloat

// Final function
let readNumbers reader =
    readInt reader, readFloat reader
// val readNumbers:
//  reader: 'a -> int * float when 'a :> IReaderInt and 'a :> IReaderFloat
```

At first, I've tried using inheritance but type inference does not work any more

```ml
// Input type
type IReader<'a> =
    abstract member readValue : 'a

// Wrapper types
type IReaderInt =
    inherit IReader<int>

type IReaderFloat =
    inherit IReader<float>

// Implementation
type NumberReader(intReader: IReader<int>, floatReader: IReader<float>) =
    interface IReaderInt with
        member _.readValue = intReader.readValue

    interface IReaderFloat with
        member _.readValue = floatReader.readValue

let readInt (reader: #IReaderInt) =
    reader.readValue

let readFloat (reader: #IReaderFloat) =
    reader.readValue

let readNumbers reader =
    readInt reader, readFloat reader
//                            ~~~~~~ Error FS0001...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Romain, you put me on track to the following:

```ml
(* Input type *)
type IReader<'a> =
    abstract member readValueTupled : unit -> 'a * 'a
    abstract member readValue : unit -> 'a

(* generic implementation *)
type GenericImplementation<'a> (a : 'a) =
    interface IReader<'a> with
      member this.readValueTupled () = (a, a)
      member this.readValue () = a

module Int =
  (* Wrapper types *)
  type IReader =
      abstract member readValueTupled : unit -> int * int
      abstract member readValue : unit -> int

module Float =
  (* Wrapper types *)
  type IReader =
      abstract member readValue : unit -> float
      abstract member readValueTupled : unit -> float * float

(* Implementation of class, using the generic implementation above *)
type NumberReader(anInt : int, aFloat : float) =
  let IReaderInt = (GenericImplementation(anInt) :> IReader<int>)
  let IReaderFloat = (GenericImplementation(aFloat) :> IReader<float>)

  interface Int.IReader with
    member _.readValueTupled () = IReaderInt.readValueTupled ()
    member _.readValue () = IReaderInt.readValue ()

  interface Float.IReader with
    member _.readValueTupled () = IReaderFloat.readValueTupled ()
    member _.readValue () = IReaderInt.readValue ()

(* Final function *)
(* val reader: 'a (requires 'a :> Int.IReader and 'a :> Float.IReader) *)
let readNumbers reader =
    (reader :> Int.IReader).readValueTupled ()
    , (reader :> Float.IReader).readValue ()
```

This would allow me to define an interface and write the implementation generically, and then pass different instantiations into functions respecting interface segregation.

I added the second member to test the refactoring, and found it painful to make the correct changes in the right places.

So I've made peace with rather passing in a tuple of required readers at the callsite, which means that I can just do something like this:

```ml
  (* Input type *)
  type IReader<'a> =
      abstract member readValueTupled : unit -> 'a * 'a
      abstract member readValue : unit -> 'a
  
  (* generic implementation - do something *)
  type Reader<'a> (a : 'a) =
      interface IReader<'a> with
        member this.readValueTupled () = (a, a)
        member this.readValue () = a
  
  (* Implementation of class, using the generic implementation above *)
  type NumberReaderAndOtherThings(anInt : int, aFloat : float) =
    member _.IReaderInt = Reader<int>(anInt) :> IReader<int>
    member _.IReaderFloat = Reader<float>(aFloat) :> IReader<float>    
  
  
  (* Called function *)
  let useReaders (readerInt : IReader<int>, readerFloat : IReader<float>) =
      readerInt.readValueTupled (), readerFloat.readValueTupled ()

  (* Call site *)
  let useAllThis = 
    let myClass = NumberReaderAndOtherThings(1, 1.1)
    useReaders (myClass.IReaderInt, myClass.IReaderFloat)
```

In my case there is currently only the generic implementation, so I have realised I can dispense with the interface altogether (for now):

```ml
(* generic implementation - do something *)
type Reader<'a> (a : 'a) =
  member this.readValueTupled () = (a, a)
  member this.readValue () = a

(* Implementation of class, using the generic implementation above *)
type NumberReaderAndOtherThings(anInt : int, aFloat : float) =
  member _.IReaderInt = Reader<int>(anInt)
  member _.IReaderFloat = Reader<float>(aFloat)

(* Called function *)
let useReaders (readerInt : Reader<int>, readerFloat : Reader<float>) =
    readerInt.readValueTupled (), readerFloat.readValueTupled ()

(* Call site *)
let useAllThis =
  let myClass = NumberReaderAndOtherThings(1, 1.1)
  useReaders (myClass.IReaderInt, myClass.IReaderFloat)
```

Thank you everyone for the help, sorry for the long post, maybe it helps someone in the future (all advice and comments welcome).